# Difference between Wiki Library and Document Library

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, wiki

Is there any difference in terms of working and customising between wiki library and Document Library.

Comment: Does not my answer help you??

Answer (score 8):

## Difference in General

**In wiki page library**, people store wiki pages & web part pages (`.aspx`). It's an interconnected set of easily editable web pages, which can contain text, images and web parts.

**In document library**, people store documents like `.doc`, `.pdf`, `.xlsx` and etc. You can use a document library to store, organize, sync, and share documents with people. You can use co-authoring, versioning, and check out to work on documents together. With your documents in one place, everybody can get the latest versions whenever they need them. You can also sync your documents to your local computer for offline access.

## Content Type Difference

When you create a document library default content type is `Document`.

When you create a document library default content types are `Wiki Page`, `Web Part Page`.

So by customizing a **Document Library**, you can add `Wiki Page` or `Web Part Page` content type to it. At the same time, you can add `Document` content type to a **Wiki Page Library**. So in terms of customization, there is no difference rather it's your choice for storing documents/files.

Also have a look [Introduction to libraries](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Introduction-to-libraries-7d4221d9-8fb9-40d5-8441-2374c84b5e26) by *Office Support*. Its said

**Document library:**

> For many file types, including documents and spreadsheets, use a
> document library. You can store other kinds of files in a document
> library, although some file types are blocked for security reasons.
> When you work with programs that are not blocked, you can create those
> files from the library. For example, your marketing team may have its
> own document library for planning materials, news releases, and
> publications.

**Wiki Page Library:**

> To create a collection of connected wiki pages, use a wiki page
> library. A wiki enables multiple people to gather information in a
> format that is easy to create and modify. You can also add wiki pages
> that contain pictures, tables, hyperlinks, and internal links, to your
> library. For example, if your team creates a wiki site for a project,
> the site can store tips and tricks in a series of pages that connect
> to each other.

Answer (score 5):

Yes there is difference,  Below might be helpful to understand.

Document library can contains documents, it can be any document like office documetnts doc,xls,ppt, js, css, jpg, png etc...any file extension you can think of. Main purpose of document library is to store documents.

wiki library is a kind of document library which contains wiki pages, Wiki pages are html pages with rich text editing capabilities so that users can create pages using Rich Text Editor without knowing html in detail. So when wiki library template is selected it comes with some default columns created based on content type, this columns are useful to create wiki page.

Making changes and edits in a wiki page is incredibly easy. Just click on the edit button (at the top of the page) and immediately the page appears as an editor’s version of the page. You can then make edits straight away and simply hit save. The page will instantly be up and running with your changes in place

Comment: How about choosing **Asset Library** for `js`, `css`, `jpg`, `png` and etc?

Comment: @AtishDipongkor...yes I already know it....it was just an example.... that document library can have anything which you want to store, you can also store aspx page though it is not meant for aspx page.

Comment: Thanks for the response, is there any difference in terms of the working of workflows between them.

Comment: Nothing that I could think of..you can enable/disable content approval workflow, publishing feature can be used on both library...can you tell us purpose of your documents and type of document you want to store ?